# Is Sql Loader bundled in the sqlplus client?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c, sql-loader

I want to know if the sqlldr tool comes with sqlplus client ? I am trying to load a .csv file using a control file. I wanted to know if on the client side only having sqlplus client would help me upload the csv into a table ? Note that its a Oracle 12 installation.

Comment: Look in $ORACLE_HOME/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlldr is available in a full client or installation of oracle  and not on the instant client version.

Refer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html